# Toggle CSS Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 forms that allows the user to change their email address and another to change their password.

Currently, they're hidden but I'd like to have 2 links that shows each form.

I've tried using `toggleClass` but I'd like it so once somebody clicks the change the password link while the change the email address form is shown, I'd like it to hide that and then show the password form and vise versa.

How can I do that?

Comment: Yes, more codz, pleeze! :)

Comment: It sounds like you already know what you want to do and the logic required? You just have to write it now. toggleClass seems like a fine way to do this.

Comment: You can always hide both at beginning, and then show only one.

Comment: Give us some code to see what you want...otherwise what you are asking is very vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just add (or remove) a class to the other form, instead of toggling it?

```
$('a.email-link').on('click',function() {
    $('form.email-form').toggleClass('hidden');
    $('form.password-form').addClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: Yes, i agree. If you are wanting the two forms on the same page but to toggle between the two just use jQuery or JS.